# why startActivity dont work? manifest or intent?

Tags: android

```
Button myButton = new Button(this);
myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View v) {
        startActivity(this,EqVisualizerCaptureAudio.class);
   }
});
```

Why its dos not work? that intent is bad?

manifest:

Comment: did you declare your activity in the manifest ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
startActivity(new Intent(Current_Activity.this,EqVisualizerCaptureAudio.class));
```

**OR**

```
startActivity(new Intent(v.getContext(),EqVisualizerCaptureAudio.class));
```

instead

```
startActivity(this,EqVisualizerCaptureAudio.class);
```

pass Activity Context for starting Activity instead of View

Answer (score 2):

Are you declare EqVisualizerCaptureAudio activity in android menifest if not  use

```
<activity
            android:name=".EqVisualizerCaptureAudio"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
startActivity(new Intent(Current_Activity.this,EqVisualizerCaptureAudio.class));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in place of yours:

```
Button myButton = new Button(this);
myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        startActivity(getApplicationContext(),EqVisualizerCaptureAudio.class);
    }
});
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Add EqVisualizerCaptureAudio activity in manifest  and use getapplicationcontext instead of this....

I think this may help you